# How to inject a repository inside a service?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I am making simple application with Symfony. I have services configured here

```
services:
app.service.comments_service:
    class: AppBundle\Service\CommentsService
    autowire: true

app.service.projects_service:
    class: AppBundle\Service\ProjectService
    autowire: true
app.service.files_service:
        class: AppBundle\Service\FilesService
        autowire: true
app.service.users_service:
            class: AppBundle\Service\UserService
            autowire: true
```

My services use repositories (comments service uses comments repository for example) and here is the constructor of `CommentsService`

Properties

```
    private $entityManager;
    private $session;
    private $manager;
    private $commentsRepository;
```

Constructor:

```
public function __construct(
    EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
    Session $session,
    ManagerRegistry $manager,CommentsRepository $commentsRepository)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    $this->session = $session;
    $this->manager = $manager;
    $this->commentsRepository = $commentsRepository;
}
```

When I try to run my application I get this error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\AutowiringFailedException: Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Repository\CommentsRepository": argument "$em" of method "Doctr
>   ine\ORM\EntityRepository::__construct()" must have a type-hint or be given a value explicitly.
>   Cannot autowire service "app.service.comments_service": argument "$commentsRepository" of method "AppBundle\Service\CommentsService::__construct()" references class "AppBundle\Repository\CommentsRepos
>   itory" but no such service exists. in C:\xampp\htdocs\WINbetTaskManager\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\AutowirePass.php:285

Any ideas how I could fix this?

Comment: Autowire has many limitations and this is one of them.  You need to use a factory to create a repository (basically EntityManager::getRepository(Comment::class)  You can search for the details and just define the repository services individually.  I think autowire should then pick them up.

Comment: @Cerad I believe it should be an answer, not comment. Upvoted though:)

Comment: @svgrafov Thanks but while I do know how repository services work I have not done much with autowire itself so I don't really know if other problems will crop up.  In other words, this is more of a guess than an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did a bit of experimenting and this seems to work:

```
// services.yml
AppBundle\Repository\CommentsRepository:
    factory: 'doctrine.orm.entity_manager:getRepository'
    arguments: ['AppBundle\Entity\Comments']
```

That should give autowire enough information to inject the repository.